# I want to get data from my Instagram page with selenium, but I'm having problems with webdriver

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep

class Instagram_Data():

    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.browser = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.main_url = "https://www.instagram.com/"
        self.password = password
        self.username = username

    def sign_in(self):
        self.browser.get("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/")
        sleep(5)
        user_name_entry = self.browser.find_element(By.NAME,  "username")
        user_password_entry = self.browser.find_element(By.NAME, "password")
        user_name_entry.send_keys(self.username)
        user_password_entry.send_keys(self.password, Keys.ENTER)
        sleep(10)
        self.browser.close()
    
    def get_basic_info(self):
        # Profil sayfasına git
        self.browser.refresh()
        self.browser.get(f'https://www.instagram.com/{self.username}/')
        sleep(7)
    
        follower_count_element = .browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'//ul[@class="x78zum5 x1q0g3np xieb3on"]/li[2]/a/span/span')
        follower_count = follower_count_element.text
        sleep(3)
    
        
        following_count_element = self.browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'//ul[@class="x78zum5 x1q0g3np xieb3on"]/li[3]/a/span/span')
        following_count = following_count_element.text
        sleep(3)
    
        post_count_element = self.browser.find_element(By.XPATH,'//ul[@class="x78zum5 x1q0g3np xieb3on"]/li[1]/span/span')
        post_count = post_count_element.text
        sleep(3)
    
        print(f'Takipçi Sayısı: {follower_count}')
        print(f'Takip Sayısı: {following_count}')
        print(f'Gönderi Sayısı: {post_count}')
        self.browser.close()


object = Instagram_Data("*","#")
#object.sign_in()
object.get_basic_info()
```

Here I want to create a class called "Instagaram_Data()". The "sign_in" function is fine and works as I want, but I am having trouble when I want to use the function called "get_basic_info()". What I want to do here is go to the profile section and get the number of posts, number of followers and number of follows from there. Here you can access the first page on the link of the page of interest and from there
I tried to find the location of the relevant codes in the HTML, then the xpath, css selector, and even the ul tag, which contains the number of posts, number of followers, and the number of following, and then I tried to access the information I wanted to get, but it still did not work. I thought there was a problem with webdriver. First, I updated Google Chrome to version 118.0.5993.71, then I deleted my webdriver and installed a webdriver compatible with 118.0.5993.71. I wanted to go to youtube.com to see if it was working and webdriver and chrome are working fine. I don't understand why the code works. [When I run it, I see the following screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22PNH.png) What is written here is: A problem has occurred and there is a button called refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_basic_info(self):
    # Profil sayfasına git
    self.browser.refresh()
    self.browser.get(f'https://www.instagram.com/{self.username}/')
    sleep(7)

    follower_count_element = self.browser.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                                       '//ul[@class="x78zum5 x1q0g3np xieb3on"]/li[2]/a/span/span')
    follower_count = follower_count_element.text                #followers number
    sleep(2)

    following_count_element = self.browser.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                                        '//ul[@class="x78zum5 x1q0g3np xieb3on"]/li[3]/a/span/span')
    following_count = following_count_element.text                  #follow number
    sleep(2)

    post_count_element = self.browser.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                                   '//ul[@class="x78zum5 x1q0g3np xieb3on"]/li[1]/span/span')
    post_count = post_count_element.text                            #post number
    sleep(2)


    profil_photo_element = self.browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"_aadp")
    profil_photo = profil_photo_element.get_attribute("src")       #profile photo


    print(f'Followers Number: {follower_count}')
    print(f'Follow Number: {following_count}')
    print(f'Post Number: {post_count}')
    print(f'Profile Photo: {profil_photo}')
```